# typescript two interface type should be same

Tags: typescript

How to ensure that two interfaces have same properties?

```
interface A {
a: string,
b: number
}
```

```
interface B {
a: any,
b: any
}
```

interface B should be look like this.

Comment: What do you mean by "ensure" here?  I don't understand what you're asking.  Please review the guidelines for [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  It may be that you just want `interface B extends Record<keyof A, any> {}` but it's hard to tell.

Comment: Adding to jcalz's comment

Even with some definition of 'ensure', I can't think of a useful scenario in which you'd want to check structural equivalence of two `interface`s, because you would know the structure of each `interface` by looking at their definitions. You should be checking your data against whatever interface is applicable at that time.

Comment: In the above example interface "B" should have all the properties of interface "A" but the property types can be different.

Comment: @jcalz  it works but not as I expected, what I want is the interface B should give me warning if I omit any one property of Interface A

Comment: `interface B extends Record<keyof A, any> {}` has every single key from `A` in it already.   There's nothing to omit.  If you need something else, please edit your question to reflect what you need.  A use case and a [mcve] would be helpful. ...   Perhaps you want to *manually* specify `B` and then add some type system check like `type EnsureExtends<T, U extends T> = void; type EnsureB = EnsureExtends<keyof B, keyof A>;`?  I am guessing because the question doesn't make this clear.

Comment: Thanks, @jcalz I got your point.